# How to find the content of a class?

Tags: powershell, class

In powershell, I can make a class like

```
class testClass {
  [string]$testvar
}
```

But not knowing this, is there a way I can get this? Like

```
[testClass] | % {$_.ScriptCode}
```

Would return

```
class testClass {
  [string]$testvar
}
```

I couldn't find anything that did this with `Get-Member` though:

```
([testClass] | gm | % {$_.name}) | % {$([testClass]).$_} | findstr "class testClass"
```

This had the output

```
bool IsSubclassOf(type type)
bool _Type.IsSubclassOf(type c)
DefinedTypes        : {testClass, testClass_<staticHelpers>}
testClass, ?powershell, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
DeclaringType             : testClass
ReflectedType             : testClass
ReflectedType          : testClass
DeclaringType          : testClass
ReflectedType          : testClass
DeclaringType          : testClass
DeclaringType              : testClass
ReflectedType              : testClass
DeclaringType              : testClass
ReflectedType              : testClass
DeclaringType             : testClass
ReflectedType             : testClass
DeclaringType    : testClass
ReflectedType    : testClass
ReflectedType          : testClass
DeclaringType          : testClass
ReflectedType          : testClass
DeclaringType          : testClass
DeclaringType              : testClass
ReflectedType              : testClass
DeclaringType              : testClass
ReflectedType              : testClass
DeclaringType    : testClass
ReflectedType    : testClass
testClass
testClass
UnderlyingSystemType       : testClass
FullName                   : testClass
AssemblyQualifiedName      : testClass, ?powershell, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
Name                       : testClass
```

Help please

Answer (score 2):

To be honest I don't know how you imagine getting the actually source code returned by a command, but if you want to find properties of an unknown class, you can use `Get-Member` or `.GetType().Properties()`.

I extended your sample class with two more properties and a method.

```
class testClass {
    [string]$name
    [int]$age
    [datetime]$birthday

    [testClass]SayHi(){
        return "Hello World!"
    }
}
$obj = [testClass]::new()
```

When running `Get-Member` you get all the properties and the method. For the properties you also get the type they expect.

```
$obj | Get-Member

   TypeName: testClass

Name        MemberType Definition
----        ---------- ----------
Equals      Method     bool Equals(System.Object obj)
GetHashCode Method     int GetHashCode()
GetType     Method     type GetType()
SayHi       Method     testClass SayHi()
ToString    Method     string ToString()
age         Property   int age {get;set;}
birthday    Property   datetime birthday {get;set;}
name        Property   string name {get;set;}
```

Alternatively, you can use the `.GetType().GetProperties()` method to get some additional information on the properties.

```
$obj.GetType().GetProperties() | Format-Table


MemberType Name     DeclaringType ReflectedType MetadataToken Module                         IsCollectible PropertyType    Attributes CanRead
---------- ----     ------------- ------------- ------------- ------                         ------------- ------------    ---------- -------
  Property name     testClass     testClass         385875969 RefEmit_InMemoryManifestModule          True System.String         None    True
  Property age      testClass     testClass         385875970 RefEmit_InMemoryManifestModule          True System.Int32          None    True
  Property birthday testClass     testClass         385875971 RefEmit_InMemoryManifestModule          True System.DateTime       None    True
```